# How to search using partial words?

Tags: search

Is it me, or can we not search using partial words in Craft CMS? This seems to be the case in the backend when search entry titles or assets, but a client has recently pointed it out on the front-end as well.

For example, we've got an entry title containing the word 'Peruvian' but searching for 'Peru' returns no results, while searching for 'Peruvian' does return a result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because Craft doesn't do fuzzy searching by default.  You'd need to use the wildcard `'Peru*'` to match `'Peruvian'`.  You can see the full list of supported search syntaxes here: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/searching

Related, you might want to vote for this feature request: http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/8459443-add-option-to-enable-fuzzy-search-as-default

**Update:**
As of [Craft 2.5](https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2750), you can enable [fuzzy](https://craftcms.com/help/enabling-fuzzy-search-by-default) searching by default.

Comment: Voted. Thanks. Can't expect site visitors to use wildcards!

Comment: If Craft had an ```onBeforeSearch``` event that exposed the search query, wildcards and other search modifiers could be added there as well – there's a feature request for this too: http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/8267127-add-events-for-onbeforesearch-and-onsearch

Comment: Just seen this has been updated. Brilliant.